# Fatal error: Class 'PMA_Util' not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\insert_edit.lib.php on line 2319

Tags: phpmyadmin

i'm using PHP version: 5.5.33
via local server name XAMPP
and the problem is when im trying to insert a new record into my table
and to use one of the function like "current_date" or "YEAR"
it's return "Fatal error: Class 'PMA_Util' not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\insert_edit.lib.php on line 2319"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTfHV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4YHF.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Solve]
the answer is you have to fix the file 'phpmyadmin/libraries/insert_edit.lib.php'
and to get the relevant code from this link.[enter link description here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/c2846af4c8fced17d1090bf9a0334b0c328b9b30/libraries/insert_edit.lib.php)
just copy and paste all the code to your 'insert_edit.lib.php' file 
instead of previous code.